# How to add Mercurial churn extension in TeamCity

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, mercurial-extension

I'd like to generate the hg churn report in my TeamCity build, but the Churn extension is not enabled by default in Hg.  On my local box, I just add churn to the [extensions] section of mercurial.ini.

Where do I put a system wide mercurial.ini so the teamcity build agent can find it and see the extension addition?  Or, better yet, is there a way to add extensions in the build step or in the TeamCity setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to provide TeamCity command line arguments for mercurial, you should be able to use the `--config` option and enable the extension with a direct path:

```
hg --config extensions.churn=/path/to/churn.py churn -r 200:300 -a test.py
```

That said, I believe that churn is included, though not enabled, in the default install so you could first try:

```
hg --config extensions.hgext.churn= churn -r 200:300
```

That worked for me locally.

This is based on reading the [Churn Wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) and using `hg help` to find the `--config` option.